# 0/1 Knapsack Heap Space

Tags: java, memory, knapsack-problem

I have a problem with 0/1 Knapsack problem. There is data which as 400 rows and 9476897 knapsack capacity. I have also another big data(10.000rows). When i run the program it gives an error in 2 dimensional array. How can i change it? By the way i changed the -Xms all situations, but it didn't work.

ERROR:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at Knapsack.simple_fill(Knapsack.java:108)
    at Knapsack.main(Knapsack.java:99)

```
    int[][] s = new int[n + 1][W + 1];

     for (int w = 0; w <= W; w++) {
        s[0][w] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        s[i][0] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int w = 0; w <= W; w++) {
            if (st[i].weight <= w) {
                if (st[i].profit + s[i - 1][w - st[i].weight] > s[i - 1][w]) {
                    s[i][w] = st[i].profit + s[i - 1][w - st[i].weight];

                } else {
                    s[i][w] = s[i - 1][w];
                }
            } else {
                s[i][w] = s[i - 1][w];
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get? Post the stack trace.

Comment: And what do you mean by having 'another big data'?

Comment: No surprises here. It would take 14GB to store this table. You'll have to do something clever.

Comment: Split up your data into more manageable chunks

Comment: ERROR: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at Knapsack.simple_fill(Knapsack.java:108) at Knapsack.main(Knapsack.java:99)

Comment: One of the techniques that I've had success with is keeping only two rows (the previous row, and the one you're currently filling). That only gives you the optimal value, not the actual selection of items. To get the selection of items, do Branch and Bound, with a perfect initial bound (you know the optimal value), so a lot is pruned.

Comment: Also, if your weights have a GCD that isn't 1, divide them all by that GCD. That doesn't happen a lot though.